# How do I place blocks out of blockspaces?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I saw [this cool elevator](https://youtu.be/QMZZA1hVimk?t=2m52s) the other day and wondered: how do you place the blocks out of blockspaces, such as for the elevator floor and roof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video you have linked does not use actual blocks, but invisible ArmorStands wearing blocks on their head:

[image: Image of an invisible ArmorStand wearing a quartz slab]

You can summon one of these as such:

```
summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {Invisible:1,Invulnerable:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:stone_slab,Damage:7,Count:1}]}
```

Entities, unlike blocks, can be moved freely, rather than only placed on a grid.